# Replacement of Berkeley DB by some in memory distributed DB possible use from Spark

Tags: python, database, apache-spark, pyspark, in-memory-database

This is a little bit more SW architectonical question than particular programming question. So I hope that it's correctly placed here.

Currently we have implemented several Python scripts that are loading around 100GB of (key value like) data to the Berkeley DB. This loading is made only once before other computations are performed. Then there are other paralelized scripts that are reading from the DB.

We always spin this mechanism up for one computation which takes around 1 hour (it's highly optimized yet). We know that potentially there can be run around million different computations like this, so we have decided to precompute everything using most likely Spark.

I would like to ask, if there already exists some possibility of distributed high speed in memory database for this that would replace Berkeley DB? (Reading all the data once, performing lot of computations in like couple of weeks with ultra fast queries)

Currently we were investigating Spark and PySpark, but using it's in memory caching seems to be way to slow in comparison with Berkeley DB.

Does anyone has some suggestions what we can possibly use here?